# How to have a good rendering with mdenoise - DTM LiDAR denoising

Tags: geotiff-tiff, dem, lidar, digital-image-processing, ascii

I'm trying to generate a clean slope map from a LiDAR DTM. Due to LiDAR high resolution, the slope map is full of noise.

So to do this, I use **[mdenoise](https://www.cs.cf.ac.uk/meshfiltering/index_files/Page342.htm)** library.
It works quite well but it generates small artefacts on DTM denoised such as little horizontal waves as on slope map below.

I have tried different settings for threshold and iterations parameters, but the problem is always the same. I have investigated in my whole code and it appears after mdenoise. Input data is a GeoTIFF that I convert to ASCII with gdal.Translate before denoising.

Has anyone encountered this problem before and found a solution?

[image]

*threshold: 0.6; iterations: 45*